# UserControl in MasterPage PageLoad Fires Multiple Times For Each Missing Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl in my MasterPage. Whenever there are missing images on a page, the Page_Load on the UserControl is fired for the number of images that are missing plus when the page itself is loading. For example, I load a page called "http://www.domain.com/test.aspx". This page has 2 missing images.

Let's say I run this line of code:
String url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

The first Page_Load will return url as:
"http://www.domain.com/test.aspx".

Page_Load is fired again for the missing image:
url = "http://www.domain.com/404.aspx?404;http://www.domain.com:80/images/image1.jpg"

Page_Load is fired again for the 2nd missing image:
url = "http://www.domain.com/404.aspx?404;http://www.domain.com:80/images/image2.jpg"

Is there a way to stop the Page_Load from firing multiple times on the UserControl when there are missing images on the page?

Comment: this does not seem normal..? I can see how the MasterPages Page_Load would happen if you were to click on a menu item for example but to call the page_load for missing images sounds like a coding / logic issue in regards to how you are loading / populating the usercontrol for the expected images.. can you show what existing code that you have for the masterpage and the usercontrol .cs in regards to loading the images..?

Comment: Are you serving up a custom 404 page that inherits from the master page?